# $\mathcal{C}^1$-bound on topologically equivalent vector fields

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-topology, dynamical-systems

Given a compact manifold $M$ and a vector field $F:M \rightarrow TM,F \in \mathcal{X}^1(M)$, one can define an assoicated dynamical system by
$$\dot{x}=F(x)$$

We call two vector fields $F_1,F_2$ topologically equivalent if there exists a homemorphism $ h: M \rightarrow M$ mapping orbits of $F_1$ to orbits of $F_2$ preserving the temporal order.
By $[F]$ we denote the equivalence classes.

---

My question is the following: Is there any known bound on the $\mathcal{C^1}$-norm between vector fields in the equivalence class, i.e. topologically equivalent vector fields?

Is there a known result on an $\varepsilon$ (depending on $F_1,F_2$)
such that
$$\forall F_1,F_2 \in [F]: \quad \|F_1-F_2\|_{\mathcal{C}^1(M) }\leq \varepsilon$$

Comment: This seems suspicious. Imagine $M=S^n$, say with $n$ odd, $F_1 = -F_2$ smooth unit vector fields.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, I can't fully understand what you inted to say

Comment: Consider $F_1(x,y)=(-y,x)$ and $F_2 = -F_1$ on the unit circle. They are quite far apart, and I believe they are topologically equivalent.